# Testing Tool Reports - "The type Apartment is not a type known to Google"

Tags: schema.org

I've added schema.org markup to a page which shows details for an apartment. I originally used the "Residence" type, like so:

```
itemtype="https://schema.org/Residence"
```

Which google - according to their Structured Data Testing Tool - likes:

[image: Successful test using "Residence" type]

However, I'd like to change the type to "Apartment" as it's more relevant for the content on the page. According to schema.org, this is a perfectly valid option: https://schema.org/Apartment

So I updated the itemtype like so:

```
itemtype="https://schema.org/Apartment"
```

But the structured data testing tool reports "The type Apartment is not a type known to Google":

[image: Unsuccessful test using "Apartment"]

I also tried testing with this tool: https://old.webmaster.yandex.com/microtest.xml which gave a similar error.

What am I doing wrong here, how am I meant to use the "Apartment" type?

Comment: (Similar question on Webmasters: [*Schema.org 'amenityFeature' under Hotel is not recognized by Google*](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/98566/17633).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Apartment` type](https://schema.org/Apartment) was introduced with [version 3.1](https://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v3.1), which is only a few days old.

Google’s SDTT typically needs some time until it recognizes new types and properties. So I would expect that the SDTT will soon stop reporting this as an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Good to know it's not something I was doing wrong.